# I can't print the Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

why does the "row" column return a value of the "float"type?And why can't I print using the "`print(df[df['row']] != 'NaN')`" string"?

```
def main():
    bulletins = os.listdir(INPUT_DATA_DIR)

    df = pd.DataFrame(bulletins)
    df.columns = ['html']
    df['html'] = df.html.apply(read_file)
    df['id'] = df.html.apply(get_document_id)
    df['res_html'] = df.html.apply(get_resolution)
    df['type'] = df.res_html.apply(get_type)

    row_index = df.index[df['type'] == 'Table'].tolist()
    df.loc[row_index, 'row'] = df.loc[row_index, :].res_html.apply(get_column_count)
    print(df[['id', 'type', 'row']].head())
    print(df[df['row']] != 'NaN')


def get_column_count(tree):
    row = tree.tbody.tr

    return len(row.findAll('td'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Error:

```
        id   type  row
0    c00897401   Text  NaN
1    c04341797  Table  2.0
2    c00896487  Table  2.0
3    c00797078   Text  NaN
4    c01894850  Table  2.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roman/etlsrc/parsers/hp_ux/app/resolution_field.py", line 83, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/roman/etlsrc/parsers/hp_ux/app/resolution_field.py", line 27, in main
    print(df[df['row']] != 'NaN')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2806, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1553, in _get_listlike_indexer
    keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1640, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([nan, 2.0, 2.0, nan, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, nan, nan,\n              ...\n              2.0, nan, 2.0, nan, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, nan, nan, nan],\n             dtype='float64', length=447)] are in the [columns]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your error is `print(df[df['row']] != 'NaN')`.

This code has several flaws.

If you want to print rows, excluding any **finite** value, e.g. *3*,
you should write:

```
print(df[df['row'] != 3])
```

(the last square bracket should be moved behind the value of interest).

But if you want to locate rows with *row* column != *NaN*:

- You can not compare the column in question with a **string**
  (*NaN* is a special case of **float**).
- Even if you applied the correct value (*np.nan*), you can not
  compare it with any other value, as *NaN* is by definition not
  equal to any other value, including other *NaN*.
- You should use a dedicated *Pandas* function named *notnull*.

So change your code to:

```
print(df[pd.notnull(df['row'])])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! your answer helped me. but I still have 1 question, why in the 'row'column contains values of the "float" type"?

Comment: *NaN* is a special case of *float*, so if at least one value in a column is *NaN* then at least just this cell is of *float* type. If all other values in this column are numeric, then this column is coerced to *float*. Other posiible case is that this column contains e.g. strings. Then such a column can not be coerced to *float*, so its type is *object*. Actually, such column contains values of various types.